# I want to update record using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update record  using laravel my record is updating successfully but not record updating  of specific id when i click update button all record is updating how can i fix it ?

Does Anyone have any idea ?

**controller**

```
             public function updateaction(Request $request,$id)
             {     
             $category=$request->input('select_category');
             $project_name=$request->input('product_name');                  
             $updaterecord=DB::table('projects')- 
             >update(['project_name'=>$project_name,'category_id'=>$category]);                
             if($updaterecord)
             {
             return redirect('view_projects');
             }
             }
```

**html view**

```
            <form action="{{route('project.update', $project->products_id)}}" method="POST" 
              >
             @csrf
            <div class="group-form">
            <select  class="form-control" name="select_category" required>
             <option value="" >Select Category</option>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option  value="{{$category->id}}" @if($project->category_id) == $category->id)  @endif> 
            {{$category->category_name}}</option>     
            @endforeach
           </select>
           </div>
          <br>
          <div class="group-form">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$project->project_name}}" 
          placeholder="Update Product Name" name="product_name" required >  
          </div>
         <br>

       <div class="group-form">
       <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary form-control" value="UPDATE"  name="Update" >  
      </div>
      </form>
```

**Route**

```
   Route::post('project_update/{id}/update','AdminController@updateaction')->name('project.update');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**controller**
you are missing `->where(['id'=> $id]);`

```php
public function updateaction(Request $request,$id)
    {     
        $category=$request->input('select_category');
        $project_name=$request->input('product_name');                  
        $updaterecord=DB::table('projects')
        ->where(['id'=> $id])->update(['project_name'=>$project_name,'category_id'=>$category]);

        if($updaterecord){
        return redirect('view_projects');
        }
    }
```

**in View**

add `@method('put')` if you are using `Resource Route`

```php
<form action="{{route('project.update', $project->products_id)}}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   @method('put')
```

Comment: I have used your controller code but  i have error  how to fix it ? please check
https://flareapp.io/share/xPQzlg71

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the specific element so find with that id & update that specific element.

```
$project=Project::find($id);
$project->update(['project_name'=>$project_name,'category_id'=>$category]);
```